# How to create a subscriptable Mock object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

Suppose, I have a code snippet as

```
foo = SomeClass()
bar = foo[1:999].execute()
```

To test this, I have tried something as

```
foo_mock = Mock()
foo_mock[1:999].execute()
```

Unfortunately, this raised an exception,

> TypeError: 'Mock' object is not subscriptable

So, How can I create a *subscriptable* ***`Mock`*** object?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use a [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) instead.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock, MagicMock
>>> Mock()[1:999]
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not subscriptable
>>> MagicMock()[1:999]
<MagicMock name='mock.__getitem__()' id='140737078563504'>
```

It's so called "magic" because it supports `__magic__` methods such as `__getitem__`.

Comment: If you plan on altering the result of a subscriptable mock, note that you have to either change `MagicMock().__getitem__.return_value` or set a new variable equal to the result of the subscription `result = MagicMock()[1:999]`.