# How to mock an attribute variable that returns a class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

So I have this class located in folder/layer/base.py which has something like this in it:

```
from folder.plugin import load_plugin

class BaseLayer:

  def __init__(self):
    self.tileindex = load_plugin()
```

I need to add unit tests to already existing functions within that class. My problem is, the function `load_plugin()` returns an instance of a class located in folder/tileindex/base.py. Because of that, it happens multiple times and in multiple different functions that a line looks like this:

```
def somefunction(self):
  key = self.tileindex.get_key(...)
  r = self.tileindex.bulk_add(...)
  self.tileindex.add(...)
```

And I have no clue how to mock that. At first I was mocking `load_plugin` and returning whatever value so I could assert it afterwards. But now that I've seen these functions that use `self.tileindex` as an instance of another class I don't know what to do. For example:

```
def register(self):
        """
        Registers a file into the system
        :returns: `bool` of status result
        """
        items = [item for item in self.items if item['register_status']]
        if len(items) > 1:
            item_bulk = []
            for item in items:
                item_bulk.append(self.layer2dict(item))
            LOGGER.debug('Adding to tileindex (bulk)')
            r = self.tileindex.bulk_add(item_bulk)
            status = r[items[0]['identifier']]
```

When I mocked `load_plugin`, the code failed at the last line saying `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not subscriptable`.

I tried to import the class that is instanciated and mock that directly. But then for some reason I get the error `AttributeError: <Group tileindex> does not have the attribute 'base'` as soon as I put `@patch('folder.tileindex.base')`.

Is there some way I can mock `self.tileindex` itself so I can test the rest of the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that to not use `unittest.mock.Mock` but instead `unittest.mock.MagicMock` for the reasons stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176468/how-to-create-a-subscriptable-mock-object). You can follow this documentation about [Mocking Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-classes) (all of this will use `MagicMock`).

For your case, here are 3 options to mock the object returned by `load_plugin()`. You can choose what best fits your needs.

- `mock_plugin_return_values` - Mocks via `return_value`
- `mock_plugin_side_effect` - Mocks via `side_effect`
- `mock_plugin_stub` - Mocks via stubbing the class

**File tree**

```
.
├── folder
│   ├── layer
│   │   └── base.py
│   ├── plugin.py
│   └── tileindex
│       └── base.py
└── tests
    └── test_layer.py
```

**folder/layer/base.py**

```
from folder.plugin import load_plugin

class BaseLayer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tileindex = load_plugin()

    def somefunction(self):
        a = self.tileindex.add("a")
        print("add:", a)

        key = self.tileindex.get_key("a")
        print("get_key:", key)

        r = self.tileindex.bulk_add([1, 2, 3])
        print("bulk_add:", r)

        status = r['identifier']
        print("status:", status)

        return a, key, r, status
```

**folder/plugin.py**

```
from folder.tileindex.base import SomePlugin


def load_plugin():
    return SomePlugin()
```

**folder/tileindex/base.py**

```
class SomePlugin():
    pass
```

**test/test_layer.py**

```
import pytest

from folder.layer.base import BaseLayer


# Note, this requires <pip install pytest-mock>


@pytest.fixture
def mock_plugin_return_values(mocker):
    mock_cls = mocker.patch("folder.plugin.SomePlugin")
    mock_obj = mock_cls.return_value

    mock_obj.add.return_value = "Anything!"
    mock_obj.get_key.return_value = "Something!"
    mock_obj.bulk_add.return_value = {"identifier": "Nothing!"}


@pytest.fixture
def mock_plugin_side_effect(mocker):
    mock_cls = mocker.patch("folder.plugin.SomePlugin")
    mock_obj = mock_cls.return_value

    mock_obj.add.side_effect = lambda arg: f"Adding {arg} here"
    mock_obj.get_key.side_effect = lambda arg: f"Getting {arg} now"
    mock_obj.bulk_add.side_effect = lambda arg: {"identifier": f"Adding the {len(arg)} elements"}

@pytest.fixture
def mock_plugin_stub(mocker):
    # Option 1: Create a new class
    # class SomePluginStub:

    # Option 2: Inehrit from the actual class and just override the functions to mock
    from folder.tileindex.base import SomePlugin
    class SomePluginStub(SomePlugin):

        def add(self, arg):
            return f"Adding {arg} here"

        def get_key(self, arg):
            return f"Getting {arg} now"

        def bulk_add(self, arg):
            return {"identifier": f"Adding the {len(arg)} elements"}

    mocker.patch("folder.plugin.SomePlugin", SomePluginStub)


def test_return_values(mock_plugin_return_values):
    layer = BaseLayer()
    result = layer.somefunction()
    print(result)
    assert result == ('Anything!', 'Something!', {'identifier': 'Nothing!'}, 'Nothing!')


def test_side_effect(mock_plugin_side_effect):
    layer = BaseLayer()
    result = layer.somefunction()
    print(result)
    assert result == ('Adding a here', 'Getting a now', {'identifier': 'Adding the 3 elements'}, 'Adding the 3 elements')


def test_stub(mock_plugin_stub):
    layer = BaseLayer()
    result = layer.somefunction()
    print(result)
    assert result == ('Adding a here', 'Getting a now', {'identifier': 'Adding the 3 elements'}, 'Adding the 3 elements')
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
...                                                                                     [100%]
=========================================== PASSES ============================================
_____________________________________ test_return_values ______________________________________
------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------
add: Anything!
get_key: Something!
bulk_add: {'identifier': 'Nothing!'}
status: Nothing!
('Anything!', 'Something!', {'identifier': 'Nothing!'}, 'Nothing!')
______________________________________ test_side_effect _______________________________________
------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------
add: Adding a here
get_key: Getting a now
bulk_add: {'identifier': 'Adding the 3 elements'}
status: Adding the 3 elements
('Adding a here', 'Getting a now', {'identifier': 'Adding the 3 elements'}, 'Adding the 3 elements')
__________________________________________ test_stub __________________________________________
------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------
add: Adding a here
get_key: Getting a now
bulk_add: {'identifier': 'Adding the 3 elements'}
status: Adding the 3 elements
('Adding a here', 'Getting a now', {'identifier': 'Adding the 3 elements'}, 'Adding the 3 elements')
3 passed in 0.06s
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very detailed and I appreciate it. There's just one thing it's that the `SomePlugin` actually comes from another folder. Inside the `load_plugin` function there is a `module = importlib.import_module(packagename)` and then from that it will return the class with the plugin definition. So what I tried to do was `@patch(folder.tileindex.base)` so that I could use it, but I always get the error `AttributeError: <Group tileindex> does not have the attribute 'base'`. The import itself `from folder.tileindex.base import module` works, but the patch always fails...

Comment: To not deal with all the complexities of `SomePlugin` further, you can just change the line `mock_cls = mocker.patch("folder.plugin.SomePlugin")` into `mock_cls = mocker.patch("folder.layer.base.load_plugin")` so that we would just patch `load_plugin()` directly instead of the class it instantiates. But this will only work for `mock_plugin_return_values` and `mock_plugin_side_effect` and not with `mock_plugin_stub` (though given those facts I think this wouldn't be preferred anyways). Could you try it?

Comment: That was what I was doing that was failing. when doing these lines: `r = self.tileindex.bulk_add(item_bulk)` `status = r[items[0]['identifier']]` it fails saying `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Are you initializing anything as a `unittest.mock.Mock` object manually that you included along with my answer? Or are you using the fixture I already provided in my answer?

Comment: uhm.. Why is the test passing now that I've changed unittest.mock.Mock for just a patch... I thought they were equivalent I guess there's a big difference. I was doing `mocked_load_plugin = Mock()` and then patching my entire test class with `@patch('folder.layer.base.load_plugin', new=mocked_load_plugin)` so I wouldn't have to pass it as an argument to every test function. Now I tried instead passing it to every function and removing the `new` and the test passes... I'm kind of pissed not gonna lie but thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can see the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176468/how-to-create-a-subscriptable-mock-object). Glad it helped :) If it's all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers